# How to use "git log --graph --oneline --all" only on my local branches?

Tags: git

I would like to see all my local branches, but none of the remote tracking refs like `origin/master`

This command shows me a nice graph decorated with all my local and remote tracking branches:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

What flag should I add/remove in this command to show only local branches?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ain't sure what you need but how about something like:

`git log --graph --oneline --branches --not --remotes=*`

*Note that it may filter out the whole log* (e.g. in the case when you have an up-to-date 
branch so there is nothing you have only locally). Please consult `git help log` for the details.

If you need only the names and the last commit you can simply use:

`git branch -v`

Probably you can mix these to fit your needs.

But my preferred choice is `gitk --all`, here's an example output:

[image]

Comment: @0x90 It shows all commits that are in any local branch but not in any remote repository branches (for details, refer to `git help log`, there you can find it discussed in details at the examples section).

Comment: This doesn't seem to ever show the results in a graph despite having --graph as a flag (tried using git 1.8.4)

Comment: I don't know when I posted it but I'm sure I tried it in the command line :-) I suppose it was around ~1.8.2, maybe the arguments changed since. You know you can propose an edit if you figure it out? :-) I don't have Git at hand atm.

Comment: Heads-up: this one doesn't show local branches that are tracking upstream branches regardless of whether they're up to date (i.e. pointing to the same commit as the upstream counterpart) or not!

Answer (score 40):

This will show you all local branches.

```
git log --graph --oneline --branches
```

From `git log --help`

> ```
> --branches[=<pattern>]
>     Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as <commit>.
>     If <pattern> is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob.
>     If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.
> ```

So `--branches` is enough. I like to add `--decorate` and give the whole command a short alias.

Comment: `--decorate` is enabled by default starting with git 2.13

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, its not perfectly clear what the question is asking, but  if like me, what you really wanted to do was *decorate* only your local branches, leaving would be remote branches undecorated, you could use a variation of the following invocation:

```sh
git log --graph --oneline --decorate-refs=refs/heads
```

where the key argument is `--decorate-refs=refs/heads`.

This would result, as an example, in going from

```
(base) jdoubled@aig35 ~/packages/solarized $ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all -n9
* 7ef17bf (HEAD -> topic_demoX) this demos going great
* b583669 (master) stupid empty commit for illustration only
* e40cd41 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) add tmux by @seebi!
*   ab3c564 Merge pull request #256 from sgerrand/add-credit-for-xfce4-terminal-port
|\
| * 4f90b03 Adds attribution for Xfce terminal port. Fixes #255.
* | 8a909d3 merge upstream xfce4-terminal changes
* | 04583c9 merge upstream gedit changes
* | f9e5943 add gedit back as a subtree
* | 53bfffc remove gedit submodule
```

to (note absence of 'origin/master' on e40c)

```
(base) jdoubled@aig35 ~/packages/solarized $ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all -n9 --decorate-refs=refs/heads
* 7ef17bf (topic_demoX) this demos going great
* b583669 (master) stupid empty commit for illustration only
* e40cd41 add tmux by @seebi!
*   ab3c564 Merge pull request #256 from sgerrand/add-credit-for-xfce4-terminal-port
|\
| * 4f90b03 Adds attribution for Xfce terminal port. Fixes #255.
* | 8a909d3 merge upstream xfce4-terminal changes
* | 04583c9 merge upstream gedit changes
* | f9e5943 add gedit back as a subtree
* | 53bfffc remove gedit submodule
```

Kudos should go to this answer on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730910/13938570

Also note, that the decorate-refs feature was added somewhere between the ridiculously ancient 1.8 (my sys admin's supplied version) and 2.28 versions of git.  Maybe someone can comment with what specific version this became possible.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I guess this is what the OP asks, and the answer is super clear with actual output (this was my requirement anyway). I also found that `--decorate-refs-exclude=refs/remotes/<remote_name>` also works if you want to hide specific remotes only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git branch | tr -d ' *' | awk '{ print "master~1.."$0 }')
```

It's not perfect, but should get you a decent output.