# Only show remotes in git log decoration

Tags: git, formatting

When I run the command `git log --oneline origin/dev...origin/release` I get output akin to:

```
e829fee14 (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev, origin/HEAD) latest commit message
d511c2de5 some other message
08e84e327 (origin/release) latest release message
eb267ff70 (release) a change in release but not in dev
```

What I'm after is:

```
e829fee14 (origin/dev, origin/HEAD) latest commit message
d511c2de5 some other message
08e84e327 (origin/release) latest release message
eb267ff70 a change in release but not in dev
```

Where only the remote branches are decorated, i.e. I do *not* want my local branches displayed.

Comment: Not really, no: the --decorate / %d directive looks at all references. You could achieve the desired result by *deleting* all the local branch names, so that they don't exist and therefore can't be displayed, but this seems like a bad idea: you'd have to do it on a clone you immediately throw away.

Comment: You could run it in your public repo. Then only pushed braches would show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git log --oneline origin/dev...origin/release --decorate-refs=refs/remotes/origin
```

`--decorate-refs=<pattern>` prints the decoration only for refs that match the pattern.

Comment: Beautiful! Played with `--decorate-refs` but used `--decorate-refs=origin/*` which obviously didn't work... What's the significance of 'refs/remotes/' (or where could I read up on this aspect of git)?

Comment: @CurtisJC Read https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces on gitnamespaces. Remote branches from the remote `origin` are under `refs/remotes/origin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command

```
git log --oneline  --remotes
```

Comment: Tags and `HEAD -> master` are still visible in decorations.